# Modifying Oracle procedure for MySQL

Tags: mysql, oracle, loops, optimization, cursors

I am really struggling to modify an Oracle procedure to MySQL, as using cursors in MySQL increases the run time from 2 minutes to 6 hours!!

Here is my Oracle Master Procedure which calls other procedures but i believe it might need a complete restructuring to work for MySQL:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE lpUsers_master AS
    v_SEASON_NUMBER_DERIVED NUMBER;
    v_LEAGUE_COUNTRY VARCHAR2(100);
    v_LEAGUE_LEVEL NUMBER;
    v_ALPHA2CODE_DERIVED VARCHAR2(2);
    v_count NUMBER;
    v_count_plus NUMBER;
BEGIN
    -- Step 1: Derive the Season Number
    ADMIN.sp_deriveSeasonNumber(v_SEASON_NUMBER_DERIVED);

    -- Step 2: Scan the LEAGUE_POOL table
    FOR r IN (SELECT lp.LEAGUE_POOL_ID, lp.LEAGUE_COUNTRY, lp.LEAGUE_LEVEL FROM LEAGUE_POOL lp) LOOP
        v_LEAGUE_COUNTRY := r.LEAGUE_COUNTRY;
        v_LEAGUE_LEVEL := r.LEAGUE_LEVEL;

        -- Step 3: Derive ALPHA2CODE_DERIVED and check for existing records
        CASE r.LEAGUE_COUNTRY
            WHEN 'Rest of Africa' THEN v_ALPHA2CODE_DERIVED := 'BJ';
            ELSE 
                -- Fetch from the COUNTRIES table
                SELECT ct.ALPHA2CODE INTO v_ALPHA2CODE_DERIVED
                FROM COUNTRIES ct WHERE ct.LEAGUE_COUNTRY = r.LEAGUE_COUNTRY;
        END CASE;

        -- Step 4: Check initial count to see if the league exists in current season
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_count FROM LEAGUE_POOL_USERS lpu
        WHERE lpu.LEAGUE_POOL_ID = r.LEAGUE_POOL_ID AND lpu.SEASON_NUMBER = v_SEASON_NUMBER_DERIVED;

        IF v_count = 0 THEN
                SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_count_plus 
                FROM LEAGUE_POOL_USERS 
                WHERE LEAGUE_POOL_ID = r.LEAGUE_POOL_ID AND SEASON_NUMBER = v_SEASON_NUMBER_DERIVED + 1;

                IF v_count_plus = 0 THEN
                -- Step 6: If the LEAGUE_POOL_ID doesn't exist in LEAGUE_POOL_USERS (and has not been added already to the next season), 
                -- THEN add NEW users to the database and create new leagues for new season
              sp_insertLeaguePoolUsers(v_SEASON_NUMBER_DERIVED, v_LEAGUE_COUNTRY, v_LEAGUE_LEVEL, r.LEAGUE_POOL_ID, v_ALPHA2CODE_DERIVED);
                END IF;

        ELSIF v_count > 0 THEN
               -- if it exists, check if the players have already been added to the next season to prevent duplication
            SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_count_plus 
            FROM LEAGUE_POOL_USERS 
            WHERE LEAGUE_POOL_ID = r.LEAGUE_POOL_ID AND SEASON_NUMBER = v_SEASON_NUMBER_DERIVED + 1;   
            IF v_count_plus = 0 THEN
          -- Step 5: add all league levels to the next season
                CASE r.LEAGUE_LEVEL
                    WHEN 1 THEN
                        ADMIN.sp_handleleaguelevel1(v_SEASON_NUMBER_DERIVED, v_LEAGUE_COUNTRY);
                         WHEN 2 THEN
                        ADMIN.sp_handleLeagueLevel2(v_SEASON_NUMBER_DERIVED, v_LEAGUE_COUNTRY);
                        WHEN 3 THEN
                        ADMIN.sp_handleLeagueLevel3(v_SEASON_NUMBER_DERIVED, v_LEAGUE_COUNTRY);
                         WHEN 4 THEN
                        ADMIN.sp_handleLeagueLevel4(v_SEASON_NUMBER_DERIVED, v_LEAGUE_COUNTRY);
                END CASE; 
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

END lpUsers_master;
```

User cursors in MySQL but the performance is terrible

Comment: Undoubtedly, every RDBMS has a different stored procedure language, each with their own strengths and weaknesses. Moving between platforms usually requires a thorough rewrite. For instance, in MySQL there is almost never a good case for using a cursor. In my opinion, there's almost never a good case for using _any_ kind of stored procedure in MySQL. MySQL doesn't implement a procedure compiler, or a debugger, or packages, or CREATE OR REPLACE to support atomic deployment, etc. I recommend to move business code into a data access layer in your application when you use MySQL.

Comment: Even if mysql stored procedures were better implemented, this question would still be unanswerable. You should provide 1) context so we can understand what the script is supposed to do and can suggest alternative logic 2) sample data and expected results so we can test if our solutions actually work 3) a reasonable attempt to solve the problem yourself just to make sure you are not trying to use us as a free coding service. Not to mention that the script calls other stored procedures we know nothing about.

Comment: Under the [SQL_MODE=ORACLE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql_modeoracle/) in MariaDB you may be able to dump the same procedure and run it there. Much of what @bill-karwin applies to MariaDB too (in this case, though it does have [packages](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-package/) and [create or replace procedure](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-procedure/)). Worth a test anyway.

Answer (score 0):

- Some little things to do:  Use `EXISTS` instead of `COUNT`.  The may be much faster, and is probably never slower.

  ```
  IF v_count = 0 THEN
            SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_count_plus 
            FROM LEAGUE_POOL_USERS 
            WHERE LEAGUE_POOL_ID = r.LEAGUE_POOL_ID
                AND SEASON_NUMBER = v_SEASON_NUMBER_DERIVED + 1;
            IF v_count_plus = 0 THEN  ...
  ```

-->

```
  IF (v_count = 0) AND NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT 1 FROM LEAGUE_POOL_USERS 
            WHERE LEAGUE_POOL_ID = r.LEAGUE_POOL_ID
                AND SEASON_NUMBER = v_SEASON_NUMBER_DERIVED + 1 )
           THEN ...
```

- Check for composite indexes, which could be faster than single-column indexes.
- Can the 4 `sp_handleleaguelevel1` procs be combined?
- Turn the processing inside-out to avoid cursors.